# Add custom 2FA on Windows XP (after login)

Tags: c++, c, windows, windows-xp, winlogon

I would like to create a custom `2FA` on Windows XP (and above) for personal computers.

I know Windows XP is discontinued, but I'm using an old program relying on Windows XP, so for now I'm stuck on it.

I can write `C/C++` code, but I don't know `C#`. So I'm trying to figure out a way to suspend `userinit` to show my app, then my app will either let `userinit` do its thing, or logout the user.

I've tried changing `userinit` in the registry to put my app which would load `userinit` itself, but it's easily hackable: My app can be closed, leaving the computer in a lockdown state, or `taskmgr` can be used to launch `userinit` or `explorer`.

If there are better way, I'm opened to suggestions, but I'd like to avoid ready made solutions (**Rohos Logon Key** works but can sometimes be worked around)

Comment: Your (and my too) way is to implement own `GINA` library and to wrap calls to MS one.

Comment: @Alexander is it limited to C# or can I write it in C/C++? Do you have a link to start with please?

Comment: Just have posted links in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can do it only on C++ to implement [GINA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secauthn/winlogon-and-gina) (for Windows XP). For Vista (and above) you need to implement [Credential Provider](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=717287). It can be implemented in both C++ and C#.